# Abstract methods in abstract classes

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

**1**. Why is it allowed in Java for abstract classes to have abstract methods?

**2**. If abstract classes are used extensively for inheritance, why would there be unimplemented methods in that class?

**3**. Why would you want to inherit an unimplemented method in a sub-class/child class?? I guess my question is

**what would be the benefit of having abstract methods in abstract classes?**

I don't get it.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: If you study something like the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) you will see one or many useful applications of this.

Comment: An abstract method is a specification that must be implemented in a concrete subclass.

Comment: don't know why this questions was put on hold because it was unclear. the questions clearly states "what would be the benefit of having abstract methods in abstract classes?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me give you an example taken from [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do).

The way to prepare coffee and the way to prepare tea is quite similar.

- Boil water
- Brew
- Pour in a cup
- Add condiments

Consider then the following class

```
public abstract class CaffeineBeverage {
  public void final prepareReceipe() {
     boilWater();
     brew();
     pourInCup();
     addCondiments();
  }

  abstract void brew();
  abstract void addCondiments(); //milk, sugar, lemon?

   void boilWater(){
     //...
   }

  void pourInCup() {
   //...
  }
}
```

Now you can define two subclasses that only need to implement part of the recipe for instance to prepare Coffee or to prepare Tea. The process of the recipe is already encapsulated in the abstract class, and the process to follow it is already defined. The subclass just need to worry about their own implementation of the steps.

Thanks to inheritance the child classes will inherit the recipe process already implemented in the abstract class, and so you could do:

```
CaffeineBeverage coffee = new CoffeeBeverage();
coffee.preperareReceipe();
```

The recipe will be followed step by step, but some of the steps will be implemented in the child class, whereas some in the parent abstract class. [Dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) is a key concept here.

Clearly this is just one of many useful applications of this concept of abstract classes.

Comment: Ok, so what if instead of this you define a `Beverageable` `interface` with a signature for both `void brew();` and `addCondiments();` methods, you remove them from `CaffeineBeverage` class and, instead, make your `CoffeeBeverage` and `TeaBeverage` `extends CaffeineBeverage ìmplements Beverageable`? Any difference?

Comment: @Pere Yes, because the only pubic method method in `CaffeineBeverage` is `prepareRecipe`. The methods `brew` and `addCondiments` are not public in the abstract class `CaffeineBeverage`. They are package protected, and in general in this skeletal classes are typically protected methods. So, if you put them in an interface you're exposing API details that should be hidden from the API consumer. The idea here is that the template method encapsulates the steps of the algorithm. In your proposed design, you're forcing the API consumers to orchestrate the algorithm themselves.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract is a class that wouldn't be instanciated. If you declare an abstract method inside an abstract class then you are sure that child classes will implement this method (they are obliged). It's like an interface.

Comment: really? Ok so you're saying that abstract methods in abstract classes can be implemented by other classes, like an interface. i thought that when implementing an interface the "implements" keyword was required on a class.

Comment: Actually an interface is an abstract class with abstract methods. It's a contract between the abstract class and subclass(es), they 'HAVE' to implement these abstract methods.

Comment: I can see the point of @mkCode because, in fact, I have the same doubt. What would be the difference between having a method signature in an `interface` instead of having it as an `abstract method` in `abstract class`, if any?

Comment: There's not much difference. The class implementing (we'll call it `A`) the `interface` or extending the `abstract` class should implement the `abstract method` (if `A` is `abstract` then it can implement it or leave it to a subclass)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if my example is going to help you to understand it.

In animal world, each animal can eat.

Agree?

but I am sure you agree not all of them do the processing of eating in the same way.

for example, fish eat its food different than a tiger

```
public abstract class Animal {

   abstract void eat();
}

public class Fish extends Animal{

    @Override
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("fish eats");
    }
}

public class Tiger extends Animal{

    @Override
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("tiger eats");
    }
```

}

This processes is called **Polymoephism**

> the ability to associate multiple meanings to one function name
>   which is eat here.

Some Note for Abstract Method:

> **1**. An abstract method has no implementation. It just has a method signature.
>
> **2**. If a class has an abstract method, the whole class must be declared abstract. Not all methods have to be abstract, even if the
>   class is abstract. An abstract class can have a mixture of abstract
>   and non-abstract methods.
>
> **3**. Subclasses of an abstract class must implement (override) all abstract methods of its abstract superclass. The non-abstract methods
>   of the superclass are just inherited as they are. They can also be
>   overridden, if needed.

Comment: Although your example goes a good deal into the way to explaining why abstract methods are needed, it does not justify the need of abstract class. You `Animal` abstract class could probably be better defined in a interface since it does not provide any kind of state or behavior whatsoever. To justify an abstract class you would expect some intermediate implementation of the methods or the holding of some reusable state. So, again, my question for you is why not interface for `Animal`?

Comment: to make life simpler for the op. I am sure you know interface is not interface anymore after java 8 cuz we can add default method to interface

Comment: You cannot add state to interfaces though, so abstract classes still have a place.

Comment: good point i did not know that. but in general my answer makes sense?